# I am creating a RESTApi in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am creating a RESTAPI with laravel. 
I want to display individual values for individual ID.

My controller class code is:

```
public function show($id){
    return Adverts::findOrFail($id);
}
```

Advert: is the Modal calss
$id = is the ID from where I want to display respective details

My route class code is:

```
Route::get('/list_advert/1', 'AdvertsController@show');
```

My url is http://zuberdest:8000/list_advert/1

I get following errors:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function
>   App\Http\Controllers\AdvertsController::show(), 0 passed and exactly 1
>   expected

How to display individaual data of single ID in restapi.Can anyone help me please?Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: i had to pass {id} instead of 1. figure it out. thanks, guys.

Comment: _I am creating a RESTApi in Laravel_ --- Good for you, please change the title to something that points to your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes

```
Route::get('/list_advert/{id}', 'AdvertsController@show');
```

If you want an API response I recommend to use json-response

```
public function show($id){
    return response()->json(Adverts::findOrFail($id));
}
```

take a look to
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#json-responses